how can i deploy angular / spring boot project on cpanel
So I have a project - a price list website
The front-end is Angular  .
The back-end is Spring Boot  .
The database is MySQL  .
How can i deploy the whole project on cpanel ?

Create a dist folder in angular project main directory using "ng build --prod" command.
Copy all those files from dist folder to "src/main/resources" directory of your java project.
then do a maven build using package and if your build is successful you wil get a jar or war folder.
then go to service provider cpanel and use the packaged jar or war for deployment on the provided server.
